# How to permanently delete Mails within scripts via MailApp?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have found the following script in this forum and works really smoothly (takes files, saves files in the right folder, etc.). Namely I receive a txt. file every morning with relative quantities which I would like to import and save to my Gdrive (to later use in other scripts). The file is named with todays date which I have used the Utilities.formatDate function to obtain.

Unfortunately every time I run the script I get all files from even from previous days which would spam my folder full in a couple of days. Therefore my question is whether one can delete the emails after the script that my google search query will not find the previous emails the following day?

Any help with this conundrum appreciated!!

P.S: Email comes from the same recipient, with an identical subject "Stock_Load", however the attachment is named "date"_Todays Date.

```
    // GLOBALS
//Array of file extension which you would like to extract to Drive
var fileTypesToExtract = ['txt'];
//Name of the folder in google drive i which files will be put
var folderName = 'GmailToDrive';
//Name of the label which will be applied after processing the mail message
var labelName = 'GmailToDrive';



function GmailToDrive(){
  //build query to search emails
  var query = 'filename:stock_'+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyyMMdd").toString()+'.gpg.txt';
  //filename:jpg OR filename:tif OR filename:gif OR fileName:png OR filename:bmp OR filename:svg'; //'after:'+formattedDate+
  for(var i in fileTypesToExtract){
 query += (query == '' ?('filename:'+fileTypesToExtract[i]) : (' OR filename:'+fileTypesToExtract[i]));
  }
  query = 'in:inbox has:nouserlabels is:unread' + query;
  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
  var label = getGmailLabel_(labelName);
  var Folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("XXX");
  for(var i in threads){
 var mesgs = threads[i].getMessages();
 for(var j in mesgs){
   //get attachments
   var attachments = mesgs[j].getAttachments();
   for(var k in attachments){
     var attachment = attachments[k];
     var isImageType = checkIfImage_(attachment);
     if(!isImageType) continue;
     var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
     var file = DriveApp.createFile(attachmentBlob);
     Folder.addFile(file);
   }
 }
 threads[i].addLabel(label);

  }
};


//This function will get the parent folder in Google drive
function getFolder_(folderName){
  var folder;
  try {folder = DriveApp.getFolder(folderName)}
  catch(e){ folder = DriveApp.createFolder(folderName);}
  return folder;
}

//getDate n days back
// n must be integer
function getDateNDaysBack_(n){
  n = parseInt(n);
  var today = new Date();
  var dateNDaysBack = new Date(today.valueOf() - n*24*60*60*1000);
  return dateNDaysBack;
}

function getGmailLabel_(name){
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(name);
  if(label == null){
 label = GmailApp.createLabel(name);
  }
  return label;
}

//this function will check for filextension type.
// and return boolean
function checkIfImage_(attachment){
  var fileName = attachment.getName();
  var temp = fileName.split('.');
  var fileExtension = temp[temp.length-1].toLowerCase();
  if(fileTypesToExtract.indexOf(fileExtension) != -1) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

Comment: show us your modification attempts and specific coding issues. otherwise this question is just asking for free coding based on a found script (not yours) which is unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: I have modified the script, and updated it to the current framework (exchanged DocList scripts which are not in use anymore, and modified them with GmailApp/DriveApp functions), this should have some value for people trying to achieve a similar task as the script I found is not compatible anymore.

Comment: The query is also custom as it searches for items based on current dates. It does have major changes to the original four year old script. Beyond that the only problem the script (and me in general) is that based on the google search query it will still find the items which are labeled, regardless of the indication of 'nouser label'.

Comment: Instead of deleting, why not add a label and the in the query just exclude that label. add ` -label:finished`  to the query

Comment: see this: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/b1L33Jtsy-A  it seems you need a different way to exclude those

Comment: Thanks for the input, this makes logical sense. It seems as the subject line remains similar gmail will categorise them as conversations. Perhaps there is a way to rename the subject after the attachment has download?

Will also try to the 'label: finished' options, but it does seem that conversations are the killer at this point, hence re-downloading all old files.